# How to use padding negative in tailwind to make it responsive?

Tags: tailwind-css

I'm using tailwind css for designing my site but making responsive is tough
can anyone help?

Comment: Can you post some code regarding your question, There is high chance your question be downvoted and closed for having no information or code example. Go to this link to read more about how to ask a good question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You cannot use padding as negative value in tailwind. Try margin as

> -m-4

> -m-16

and u can refer [tailwindcss.com](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/margin/) for more reference

Comment: For those who're using tailwind with prefix `tw-` , it will be double hyphens for negative value. eg `tw--mt-2`

Answer (score 5):

You can write your custom value like this even negative value too,

`py-[-30px] mx-[-20px] translate-y-[-50%] translate-x-[-50%]`

Comment: I kept writing `-mt-[20px]` and not understanding. Thank you for this syntax. Interestingly enough for `left`, this syntax works: `-left-[1.5rem]`

Answer (score 2):

Inside tailwind.config.js file, you can extend Tailwind with your own custom utility classes where you can easily add a custom class something like

```css
neg-m-16:{margin:-1rem}
```

and use it in your component. For more you can refer to [tailwindcss.com on Adding custom utilities](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/adding-new-utilities)

Answer (score 0):

In case you've defined your own theme values in *tailwind.config.cjs* and you use the [`theme()`](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/functions-and-directives#theme) tailwind function and you want to use the negative value, you can use [`calc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) function to multiply the value by -1 which will result in the intended value:

```css
.your-selector {
    margin-bottom: calc(-1 * theme('spacing.5'));
}
```

Note that you can't use negative padding, only margin, as mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62589331/8349769).